# django subdomain blank page with frame

Tags: django

I'm using django subdomain using the script:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SubdomainMiddleware:
    """ Make the subdomain publicly available to classes """

    def process_request(self, request):
        domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
        if (len(domain_parts) > 2):
            subdomain = domain_parts[0]
            if (subdomain.lower() == 'www'):
                subdomain = ''
            domain = '.'.join(domain_parts[1:])
        else:
            subdomain = ''
            domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']

        request.subdomain = subdomain
        request.domain = domain

        if subdomain != 'www' and subdomain != '':
            # Buscamos el usuario del subdominio
            try:
                request.usuario_subdominio = User.objects.filter(username=subdomain)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
```

the problem it's when i use a frame, i get a blank page. ie:

```
<frameset rows='100%, *' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
<frame src="http://sitio.domain.com/" name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></frame>
</frameset>
<noframes><h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your browser.</h2><br><br>
<center>Click <a href="http://sitio.domain.com/" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
</noframes>
```

any solutions ? thanks.

regards,

Comment: I don't think those two are related.. Does it work if you remove the middleware?

Comment: hi, not work the domain if i remove the middleware.

Comment: Hi Damian, you got some advance?